# Scaladoc swallowed @throws and @note tags

Tags: scala, scaladoc

When creating a Scala documentation I also use the `@throws` and `@note` tags like documented [here (Scaladoc Wiki - Tags and Annotations)](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SW/Tags+and+Annotations).

Unfortunately I can't find these in the generated **Scaladoc**.

Do one have to set certain switches, consider something specific or is this a known problem?

BTW: using the `scaladoc` *Ant task* of Scala 2.9.0.1 that issues no warning too.

**EDIT:** BTW2 and to clarify: I do not mean the `@throws` annotation

```
@throws(classOf[RuntimeException])
def dispatch: Nothing = throw new RuntimeException
```

which is documented in the annotations section of this `def` but the `@throws` tag for Scaladoc like

```
/** @throws RuntimeException
 */
def dispatch: Nothing = throw new RuntimeException
```

Comment: Which version of Scala are you using? The support for `@throws` seems fairly recent (May/June 2011): https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/23

Comment: Did you tried with 2.9.1 final?

Comment: @throws does not get ignored with 2.9.0.1. It works with my version of scaladoc. At least, they appear in the Annotations section.

Comment: @VonC I've just tried 2.9.1 final (with scaladoc from command line) => it seems to be the same. But the tags `@throws` and `@note` are well known by the tool - because if one writes the tag incorrectly (eg `@notes`), then there is indeed a `warning: Tag '@notes' is not recognised`.

Comment: @binuWADa: ok, then following Matthew's comment, is it possible that those tags are taken into account, but that you are looking for them in the wrong place? Or that they are somehow hidden by the stylesheet?

Comment: @VonC and Matthew Farwell: answered with an edit - I think `@throws` annotation and `@throws` tag are not exactly the same thing.

Comment: Yes, you're right, they are different things. I misunderstood the question, and I'm getting the same behaviour as you.

Answer (score 4):

I [added support for `@note`](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/21) half a year ago.

If you have a look here, it seems to work correctly: [scala.util.matching.Regex](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex)

The other things is the `@throws` ScalaDoc tag. Actually I'm thinking about removing support for it in favor of the `@throws` annotation, which is supported, because I can't see any use case where one would prefer the ScalaDoc tag to the annotation.

If you have a real need please let me no, let me know!

Edit: Mhhh. Looking at [scala.Array](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.Array) it actually looks like it is the other way around...

Comment: An use case would be a more **detailed explanation** of when (why, under what condition) the exception is thrown, e.g. `@throws RuntimeException when something happen` which is inpossible with the `@throws` annotation, that only tells you that this exception _could_ be thrown.

Comment: I'm just keeping an eye on your link and I must say **wow** - the syntax highlighting from the nightly build Scaladoc code sections looks so great! That wasn't the issue, but had to be said ;-)

Comment: Did the change actually make it into 2.9.1? I can't see 25042 in http://www.scala-lang.org/node/10743

Comment: @binuWADa: What about having something like `@throws(clazz: Class[_], reason: String = "")`? Would that be usable for you?

Comment: @soc: Of course, that would fulfill its purpose. But for my interest: What is the `@throws` annotation good? Or more precisely: What tool (except Scaladoc) could use its information (perhaps without `reason`)?

Answer (score 3):

This is a combination of a bug and something that hasn't made it into a release yet.

@note does not work, this is a known bug, see [@todo, @note and @example don't work?](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4421)

@throws was only added recently, see this [pull request](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/23) from [Simon Ochsenreither](https://stackoverflow.com/users/297776/soc), which was merged in July 2011. This hasn't yet made it into a release, 2.9.0.1 was released in May 2011, and 2.9.1 was started in July 2011.

Comment: @Matthew Farwell: Does this mean that `@throws` could be available with next version > 2.9.1?

Comment: @binuWADa I would imagine so.